# Make the text to be in the middle of the image when mouse hovers over the image

Tags: html, css

I wanted to add a heading(bold) and a subheading(not bold) on all the images on a webpage when mouse hovers over it. I already have the effect where the image fades/changes color upon hovering. Following is the image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaOw5.jpg

Here's the HTML code for it:

```
<div class="JA-linkWrap JA-Notprojects JA-NotObjects floatleft" style="width:300px;">

        <a href="https://canadacouncil.ca/initiatives/venice-biennale" 
        class="JA-projectPageLink">

          <img src="images/GRID/111%20jpeg%20grid.jpg" alt="" class="JA- 
newsmediaImage">
         <h2 class = "img_head"> The Octa. </h2>
         <p class = "img_description"> Arch. </p>

            </a>  

    </div>
```

This is the CSS for .JA-linkWrap:

```
.JA-linkWrap {
   float: left;
   margin: 12px;
}
```

More CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}


.JA-linkWrap img:hover {
    -webkit-filter: brightness(90%);
}


.img_head{
  position: absolute;
  color: #000;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity.2s, visibility .2s;

}

.img_description{
  position:inherit;

  color:#000;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity.2s, visibility .2s;
}

.JA-linkWrap:hover .img_description{
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}



.JA-linkWrap:hover .img_head{
   visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Here's the outcome of my attempt when I hover the mouse over the image: https://imgur.com/a/Fkuf0eE ***As you can see the heading and description of the image are both under the image. I want them to be in the center of the image.*** Please be specific, I am new to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a wrapper to the title elements, and then set the size of the wrapper like the box of the image. Then use flexbox to vertically align titles inside the wrapper. Also, remove inline styles for width: 300px

```css
.JA-linkWrap {
   float: left;
   margin: 12px;
  position: relative;
}

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}


.JA-linkWrap:hover img {
    -webkit-filter: brightness(90%);
}


.img_head{
  color: #000;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity.2s, visibility .2s;
}

.img_description{
  color:#000;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity.2s, visibility .2s;
}

.JA-linkWrap:hover .img_description, .JA-linkWrap:hover .img_head {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.title-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column; 
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.title-wrapper .img_head, .title-wrapper .img_description {
    background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="JA-linkWrap JA-Notprojects JA-NotObjects floatleft">

        <a href="https://canadacouncil.ca/initiatives/venice-biennale" 
        class="JA-projectPageLink">

          <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/500/300" alt="" class="JA- 
newsmediaImage">
          
          <div class="title-wrapper">
         <h2 class = "img_head"> The Octa. </h2>
         <p class = "img_description"> Arch. </p>
          </div>

            </a>  

    </div>
```

Comment: Hey thanks a lot! I got the text to be visible on the image when you hover over it but now I lost the functionality of it fading away. What changes should I make to: .JA-linkWrap img:hover { -webkit-filter: brightness(90%); }

Comment: .JA-linkWrap:hover img  { -webkit-filter: brightness(90%); }  instead of .JA-linkWrap img:hover. I updated the answer.

Comment: Omg yeah I totally missed that! Thank you!!